# Delete subdirectories leaving a given one

Tags: bash, shell-script, files

I need to delete all sub directories and their contents in a given folder, whilst leaving a particular sub directory. Is there a way to do this using bash or a shell script? The file structure is shown below.

```
container_dir
│
├── delete_this_dir
│   ├── file1.txt
│   └── file2.txt
│
├── delete_this_dir
│   ├── l1.txt
│   └── l2.txt
│
└── keep_this_dir
    ├── file1.txt
    ├── file2.txt
    └── file3.txt
```

Comment: Can't you just backup directory which you want to leave and delete recursively container_dir ?

Comment: What is your criteria to delete or keep a particular subdirectory?

Comment: The criteria is the name of the directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In bash, use [extglob](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pattern-Matching) to exclude the directory you want to keep:

```
shopt -s extglob
rm -rf container_dir/!(keep_this_dir)
```

Answer (score 0):

Backup this container_dir and try this:

```
find $container_dir/* -path $keep_this_dir -prune -o -name "*" -type d -exec rm -rfv {} \;
```

But I recommend to use simpler solution with backup

Answer (score 0):

If it is only name by which you identify what directory to keep, then you could do as follows:

```
cd container_dir && \
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d ! -name . ! -name keep_this_dir -exec rm -r {} +
```

Meaning, change over to the container dir, then launch a `find` from there but only till depth levels of 1 and search only amongst directories at that level. From this pool of directories that `find` acquires, keep off just two, viz., the container_dir and the keep_this_dir. Rest all to be culled.